# How to get html markup of google.com using curl

Tags: php, curl

I'm write the follwoing:

```
    $ch= curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 
            "http://google.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    $output= curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
if($output==FALSE) return 'No markup';
    return $output;
```

and html markup for receiving markup of `google.com`:

```
<div class="content">
    <pre>
       <?php
            echo htmlentities($output);
        ?>

    </pre>
</div>
```

But when I'm running this script pre tag is contain **nothing**. Why? If I replaced google.com to stackoverflow.com then it works fine. How to fix this?

Comment: I guess that Google blocks the user agent of curl.

Comment: I guess that google redirects you from `http` to `https`.

Comment: With your code I get a valid response and a string length of 44,822

Comment: for debugging curl requests i do 2 things: 1) [curl_getinfo](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-getinfo.php) for debugging headers 2) [curl_setopt](http://us2.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true); for extended information about request proccess